# VUEJS vuex can't show the API fetching data on dropdown nav item

Tags: vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to use VUEX on my VUEJS App that get the data from an API, and show the names in the dropdown nav item, and the selected name will be shown in the dropdwon nav item,
but somehow can't show it and can't select the dropdown nav item, here's my code

[image]

store/index.js

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
   state: () => ({
     users: [
       {
         name: '',
         email: ''
       }
     ]
   )},
   mutations: {
     getAllUsers(state, userList) {
       state.users = userList
     }
   },
   actions: {
     async fetchAllUsers({ commit }) {
       const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
       commit('getAllUsers', res.data)
     }
   },
   getters: {
     allUsers(state) {
       return state.users
     }
   }
})
```

Navbar.vue

```
<b-navbar-nav>
   <b-nav-item-dropdown :text="userName" >
      <b-dropdown-item 
        v-for="(user, i) in userInfo" 
        :key="i"
        @click="selectName(user)"
      >
      {{ user.name }} </br>
      {{ user.id }}
      </b-dropdown-item>
   </b-nav-item-dropdown>
</b-navbar-nav>


<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedName: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
       ...mapGetters({
     userInfo: 'allUsers'
    }),
    userName() {
      return `${this.userInfo[0].name} (${this.userInfo[0].id})`
    }
  },
  methods: {
     selectName(user) {
       if (user.name !== this.selectedName) {
         this.selectedName = user.name
       }
     }
  }
}
</script>
```

what am I missing here, I can't select the names in the dropdown nav item?

Comment: `v-for="(user, i) in users"`  you don't have any data or computed variable called `users`.  did you mean to use `userListApp`?

Comment: yeah sorry typo

Comment: syntactically, there's nothing else that stands out to me.  you'll need to debug and get more information about your app's state.  have you confirmed that `$store.state.users` has an array of user values and/or have you verified the result of `fetchAllUsers` is correct?